# how to convert an array to an index in python

Tags: python, pandas

I had some code in which I had a Pandas Series, called index, and I dropped values from that using `tickers.drop()`

It was of the form:

```
Index([u'EUR3m', u'EUR3m3m', u'EUR6m3m', u'EUR9m3m', u'EUR1y', u'EUR1y1y',
       u'EUR2y1y'],
      dtype='object')
```

However, I am rewriting some code, and in this instance, I only have an array:

```
array([u'EUR3m', u'EUR3m3m', u'EUR6m3m', u'EUR9m3m', u'EUR1y', u'EUR1y1y',
       u'EUR2y1y'], dtype=object)
```

I cant locate the function to convert from array to index?

Comment: Pandas? If so, please tag it appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think converting to `Index` is not necessary, simply assign it or use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df.index = arr
```

Or:

```
df = df.set_index(arr)
```